# Characterization of a projection operator in $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convex-analysis, inner-products, linear-transformations

Let $X$ be a closed convex set in $\mathbb R^n$  and $y\in \mathbb R^n$. Suppose a  projection $T_X: \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$  satisfies

$$T_X( \alpha y+ (1-\alpha) T_X(y))=T_X(y)$$
for all $\alpha\in[0,1]$ and
 $$T_X(y)=y$$ 
if $y\in X$.

Then what would be implications of the above conditions?

Is it possible to show that $T_X$ must be of the form

$$P_X(y)=\arg\inf_{x\in X}\|x- y\|_a$$

where $\|.\|_a$ is from some parameterized family, i.e. $1\leq a\leq \infty$ ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The equation means, that the projection of points on the line segment between $y$ and $T_X(y)$ is $T_X(y)$. All projections in Hilbert space onto a non-empty, closed, and convex set share this property.

To see this, let $C$ be non-empty, closed, and convex with the  $X\subset C$. Define 
$$
P_C(y):= \operatorname{arg min}_{x\in C}\|x-y\|_2.
$$
Then $P_C$ has the properties mentioned for $T_X$ in your post. Hence, $T_X$ is not necessarily the projection onto $X$, but can be the projection onto any super-set of $X$.

---

The mapping  $T_X$ is not necessarily a projection. Define $X=\{(x_1,x_2): x_1\in[0,1], x_2 =0\}\subset \mathbb R^2$. Define $T_X$ by
$$
T_X(x) = \begin{cases} x & \text{ if } x\in X,\\
(0,0) & \text{ if } x_1<1/2, x_2 \ne0\\
(1,0) & \text{ if } x_1\ge1/2, x_2 \ne0.
\end{cases}
$$
This should satisfy that the line between $y$ and $T_X(y)$ is mapped to $T_X(y)$. Moreover, $T_X$ is discontinuous, so it cannot be a projection onto a convex set in a Hilbert space.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But does the equation necessarily imply that $T_X$ must be of the form as a projection of y onto some  $C$?  What would be the necessary conditions?

Comment: The equation $P_C(\alpha y+(1-\alpha)P_C)y))=P_C(y)$ is true not only when $P_C$ is the metric projection in the Euclidean sense but even for metric projections in reflexive Banach spaces with strictly convex norm.

Comment: @user91360 see edit

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think it seems a possibility to determine the specific form of the operator by adding more properties. Could any literature discuss this problem?

Comment: Idempotent linear operators $T$ which are not self-adjoint satisfy $T(\alpha y+(1-\alpha)y)=T(y)$ but are not metric projections in the Euclidean sense.